# Titanium console not behaving as of late

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am using `Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.3.201309132423`, `Titanium Mobile 3.1.3.GA SDK` and `iOS7 SDK`

My console has been acting weird where when I compile, I get this message:

```
[ERROR] :  An error occurred running the iOS Simulator
[ERROR] :  [DEBUG] using retina iphone retina tall ios 7
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 21s 326ms
```

Yet the project did build and compile and launch in the emulator just fine. The problem with this is now any of my debugging properties that I output to the console, I cannot see because Titanium Studio thinks the app never ran so it isn't listening anymore.

I did notice that after I build and compile again, I can see all my previous debug statements in the console. It's like the console is one build behind or something. Is anyone else have weird issues like this?

Comment: Could you try building project with `titanium build -p ios` command and see what logs will show up there?

Comment: @daniula when I run that from terminal this is what I get back `{'args': ['-p', 'ios'], 'dir': '/Users/ronnie/Desktop/Titanium Projects/vforummobile_vers'}`

Comment: @daniula ok so instead of `titanium` I used `ti` which did build and compile the app and my debug properties are properly traced out. That would mean a problem with Ti Studio then right?

Comment: ok I think I understand what is happening. If I `clean` the project, the console works for the first time in Titanium. When I close the emulator, that doesn't get translated to the console so the console keeps thinking the emulator is still running.